# Can we use multiple autocomplete extender control on single textbox in asp.net?

Tags: autocomplete

Can we use multiple autocomplete extender control on single textbox in asp.net?
This should be like this. When first list will appear then on selection of any item, populates another (2'nd" list so on up to 3-4 list. is this possible in asp.net with c#?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you'll get this out of the box.  I'm a little unclear as to exactly what you want this to do (what text winds up in the textbox?) - would this be better done using a set of dropdown lists?  IMO that is a more intuitive user interface.

Comment: 1) When user try to write the person name it should populate the related all person names according to the prefix string which is typing.
2) Again , as user selects the person name , then extender must populate the “Regions” in for select. 
3) As Regions will selects then, all department should be populates as list in extender control.

Comment: @Lalit - I'd stick with my statement then - cascading dropdown lists is a much more intuitive interface for this than a textbox extender.

Comment: No paddy, cascading dropdown lists is like the filers. but see my above comment again. I want all this functionality on single text box.

Can we change the web method name of the extender control on some event as it fired?

Comment: I think you'll probably need to code this from scratch, I don't imagine that this is something you'll get out of the box.  I think the source code is available to give you a starting point...

Comment: see paddy try this link, I know you know ,
http://www.google.co.in/
and try to print "asp" then hit space bar You will get another options right? like "asp . Net " , "asp net tutorial"...ok? if you select "asp.Net" and hit again space it will offer you another options for choose. So how this happening then? try and tell me please.

in short I want to develope Google search box like functionality.

Comment: @Lalit - this isn't really what I thought you were asking for.  You have a site that does what you want, it uses client script, go have a look at the script...  This looks like normal autocomplete functionality, you're just extending the string you enter into the box which then limits the searches.

Comment: yes, exactly. but how to implement this. JavaScript is new for me.which part of script will useful for this functionality then? please guide

Comment: Means autoextender provide me what i want but on hitting space bar I want different list let say countries...like this.